# Automating HTML color picker dialog using selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to **Selenium**.
I need to automate color picker dialog using **Selenium** for Chrome. Does anyone here have idea how can I do that?

Comment: what color picker? have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. What does the color picker look like? Do you have an option to specify RGB? or hex code?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate color picker using the JavaScriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(sampleJS);
```

Here, sampleJS can be a javascript like this:

```
String sampleJS = "document.getElementById('color').value='#ffffff'";
```

or jQuery like this:

```
String sampleJS = "$('#color').value='#330000'";
```